# Question in general measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\nu_n$ be a sequence of signed measures. Suppose there exists $c>0$ such that $\nu_n(X)\le c$ for all $n\ge 1$ and $$\nu(E)=\sum_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\nu_n(E)}{2^n}$$ for all $E\in M$.

My question is :- how to show that each measure $\nu_n$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\nu$?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, note that for every $n$ and for every measurable set $E$, $\nu_n(E)/2^n\leq \sum_{m=1}^\infty \nu_m(E)/2^m$ since the sum on the left hand side consists only of positive terms. Therefore, if $\nu(E)=0$, $0\leq\nu_n(E)/2^n\leq \sum_{m=1}^\infty \nu_m(E)/2^m=\nu(E)=0$. It follows that $\nu_n(E)=0$ and that $\nu_n\ll\nu$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: This is true if we know that $\nu$, $\nu_n(E) \geq 0$ for all $E \in M$, for all $n$.  But if this is not the case (i.e., if $\nu$, $\nu_n$ are signed measures), then perhaps one could still reach the same conclusion by adapting the Radon-Nikodym Theorem to this setting.

Comment: I am sure since measure is $\sigma-$finite we can apply Radon-Nikodym, but my question, what will be our choice about the non-negative measurable function $f$.

Comment: You need to do a Hahn-Jordan decomposition of $\nu_n$ for each $n$, which will give you insight on the functions you could choose.  Namely, the Hahn-Jordan decomposition will give you a somewhat natural choice of functions, and you can then carry the proof of Radon-Nikodym over almost verbatim to establish the result you seek.